# how to correct the a style when under IE6/7

Tags: html, css

http://down123.xxmn.com/test/

the content in the red border which displays disorder when under IE6/7.but ok under IE8 and firefox.is there a way to correct it?thank you.

Comment: Just FYI - Microsoft doesn't even support IE7 anymore, people still use it, but IE6 and under realistically you shouldn't have to worry about... since it's not supported by almost everything.

Comment: @Andy: It is an interesting point of view, but in some cases, certain jobs (unfortunately) require that we develop for these versions no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @FredWuerges Oh I agree, ideally we wouldn't even have to worry about any old browsers, but 6 and below is 3, 4+ versions behind. So I was just curious what the job was in which they were needing less than IE6. If it's a basic USA website, for example, perhaps it was just an old article being referenced saying to test for IE5.5 etc... and if that was the case I was just saying you could most likely not worry about it.

Comment: @FredWuerges To see how much of the world use IE6, go to http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I already knew this site, this information is really interesting. For us developers will be a wonder if these versions run out of time problematic. But I keep saying, unfortunately there are still specific cases where we still need to develop. Sincerely have not yet had to develop for IE6, IE7 had but for many cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you use a css reset all styles to maintain compatibility between browsers.
There are various models and examples on the internet, I use this in my projects:

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align: left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border: 0;
}
/* HTML5/IE 6,7,8 */
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
```

Comment: thank you,i put your code in ,but it doesn't resolve the question.

Comment: So to maintain compatibility between browsers you must define specific styles for these versions as follows:

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->

Comment: i put your condition code in my page,but when test it on IETEST. the page doesn't invoke the ie.css? why/

Answer (score 0):

Maintain Separate CSS files for IE versions
   and mention this CSS conditional comment in your page header. Test in orignial IE browsers.